# Integral of a complex function along a curve

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem.
Let $f$ be a entire function. Meaning, $f$ is holomorphic on whole $\mathbb{C}$ plane.
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I need to calculate this integral:
$$ \int_{C} \frac{f(z) dz}{(z-1)(z-2) \cdots (z-n)}
$$ 
where $C$ is a curve given with $x^2 + 2y^2 = 2$.

So C is an ellipse.
I will name the function under the integral $g(z)$. Function $g$ has one root at  $z= 1$ inside the area bounded with $C$. Let's call this area $D$.
I cut a small disk $K(1, \epsilon)$ out of $D$.
$\epsilon < \sqrt{2} -1 $
Using Cauchy's theorem, $$ \int_{\partial D'} g(z) dz = 0$$
where $D' = D \backslash K(1, \epsilon)$
So 
$$
0 = \int_{\partial D'} g(z) dz = \int_{C} g(z)dz - \int_{K(1, \epsilon)} g(z) dz
$$
$$
\int_{C} g(z)dz = \int_{K(1, \epsilon)} g(z) dz = \int_{0}^{2\pi} g(1 + \epsilon e^{it}) 
$$
where I parametrized $K(1, \epsilon)$ with $ z = 1 + \epsilon e^{it} $ and $t \in [0, 2\pi] $.
$g$ becomes
$$ \frac{f(1 + \epsilon e^{it}) i \epsilon e^{it}}{\epsilon e^{it}(\epsilon e^{it}- 1) \cdots (\epsilon e^{it} - n + 1)} = i \frac{f(1 + \epsilon e^{it})}{(\epsilon e^{it}- 1) \cdots (\epsilon e^{it} - n + 1)} 
$$
Since $f$ is holomorphic it is continuous and I can calculate the limit of this function for when $\epsilon$ approaches zero.
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} i \frac{f(1 + \epsilon e^{it})}{(\epsilon e^{it}- 1) \cdots (\epsilon e^{it} - n + 1)} = i \frac{f(1)}{(-1)(-2) \cdots (- n + 1)} = i \frac{f(1)}{(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!}
$$
Now i calculated the integral:
$$
\int_{C} \frac{f(z) dz}{(z-1)(z-2) \cdots (z-n)} = \int_{0}^{2\pi} i \frac{f(1)}{(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!} dt = 2\pi i \frac{f(1)}{(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!}
$$
To me it looks ok, but I am not sure all the steps are valid. Are there any mistakes or is this a fine way for calculating such integrals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative way**, without using residue theorem, but still using [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), stating:

$$g(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{C}\frac{g(z)}{z-w}dz$$
in this case $$g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{(z-2)(z-3)...(z-n)}$$
and 
$$g(1)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{C}\frac{g(z)}{z-1}dz=
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{C}\frac{f(z)}{(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)...(z-n)}dz$$
and the result follows.

*Important remark:* Cauchy integral formula works for any closed rectifiable curve. Moreover, as for the Cauchy integral theorem, it is sufficient to require that $g$ be holomorphic in the open region enclosed by the path and continuous on its closure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of the Residue Theorem? The value of the integral is $2\pi i \frac {f(1)} {(1-2)(1-3)\cdots (1-n)}$ and this is an immediate application of the theorem. Your answer is therefore correct.

Comment: Ah, that is great, I'll take a deeper look into it. Thank you.